# Comparison matrix using data that is not formatted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a little VBA script but I'm kind of stuck. 
I have an Excel file with some criteria (column A) that all have sub-criteria, as you can see below.
[image]

I'm trying to get a new sheet that looks something like this :
[image]

I've tried to think about ways to handle it but I don't know how to write it "properly", especially the first half.

```
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Count_crit = 0

For i = 3 To .Cells(.Cells.Count)
     If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
    Count_crit = Count_crit + 1
    End If
Next
For i = 0 To Fact(Count_crit)
'this is where i don't know how to handle it


End Sub
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated !

Comment: Please be more specific!!

Comment: I have criteria with sub-criteria. I'm trying to create all the possible combinations of criteria but the presence of the sub criteria prevents me from navigating between the criteria because there is a variable number of line between each criteria.